# parse JSON values from url help required

Tags: android, json

in my code json vlaue not show help me worldpopulation vlaues wil show on screen but  worldpopulation2 values not show what is error in my code?   check my xml file please help me  check my code why worldpopulation1 value show y worldpopulation2 value not show???

```
         CategoryAPI = Utils.CategoryAPI2;


    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 
      15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(CategoryAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
               InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }


             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

            JSONObject person=(new JSONObject("worldpopulation2"));
             String Name=person.getString("describtion");
             String url2=person.getString("url");
             txtdescription.setText("json values are"+Name+""+url2);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 



                  Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("rank")));
                 Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
                 Category_image.add(object.getString("url"));

                Log.d("Category name", Category_name.get(i));
                 listview.setAdapter(cla);


             }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //  IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }  



}






                  {
"worldpopulation": [
{
 "rank":1,
 "name": "Angelina",
  "url": "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/angie.jpg"
 },
 {   
 "rank":2,
 "name": "Ashton ",
  "url": "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/ashton.jpg"
 },
 {  
 "rank":3,
 "name": "Jackman",
  "url": "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/hugh.jpg"
}

]
,
"worldpopulation2": 
{
"rank":1,
"describtion": "Super mazaydar biryani",
 "url": "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_JU_j7jj5TjU/TSBQKRukf1I/AAAAAAAAAs8/X1w5_z6pjwQ   
 /s1600/chicken-biryani.jpg"
 }



   }
```

Comment: `new JSONObject("worldpopulation2")` is not a valid jsonobject declaration.

Comment: i follow this url  http://androidbite.blogspot.com/2013/01/android-json-parser-example.html  to add another array in my xml file  worldpopulation2

Comment: then how do i parse worldpopulation2 data in textview???

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to show worldpopulation2 values from xml  to show in textview how i create seprate aray or object to show on screen using same http url??

Comment: what xml? there is no xml in your code. why don't you use getJSONArray same as for worldpopulation anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

JSONObject person=(new JSONObject("worldpopulation2"));
```

Do something like this to create new jsonObject from response JSON array.

```
 JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
```

Now run a loop on JSONArray data, and see what you want to get from JSON objects.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject person = data.getJSONObject(i);
    String population2 = person.getString("worldpopulation2");
   }
```

Comment: ur code show error on this line
person=data.getJSONObject("worldpopulation2"); 

The method getJSONObject(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: I said do something like that, Not exactly what i wrote here. Try to find how you can get jsob object from JSON array object.

Comment: Edited my Answer see this.